# Symfony 2 - ManyToOne Bidirectional relationship behaviour

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, many-to-one

I had a big time trying to figure out how to setup a `ManyToOne` -> `OneToMany` relationship with Doctrine 2 and it still not working...

Here is the application behaviour:

1. A site has `Page`s
2. A `User` can write `Comment` on a `Page`

Here are my Entities (simplified):

Comment Entity:

```
**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="comment")
 */
class Comment {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     protected $id;

    /**
     * Many Comments have One User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="comments")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Many Comments have One Page
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Acme\PageBundle\Entity\Page", inversedBy="comments")
     */
    protected $page;

    ...

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setUser(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set page
     *
     * @param \Acme\PageBundle\Entity\Page $page
     * @return Comment
     */
    public function setPage(\Acme\PageBundle\Entity\Page $page)
    {
        $this->page = $page;
        return $this;
    }
```

User Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * The User create the Comment so he's supposed to be the owner of this relationship
     * However, Doctrine doc says: "The many side of OneToMany/ManyToOne bidirectional relationships must be the owning
     * side", so Comment is the owner
     *
     * One User can write Many Comments
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\CommentBundle\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $comments;

    ...

    /**
     * Get Comments
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getComments() {
        return $this->comments ?: $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Page Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="page")
 */
class Page
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * One Page can have Many Comments
     * Owner is Comment
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Acme\CommentBundle\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="page")
     */
    protected $comments;

    ...

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getComments(){
        return $this->comments ?: $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

I want a bidirectional relationship to be able to get the collection of `Comment`s from the `Page` or from the `User` (using `getComments()`).

**My problem is** that when I try to save a new `Comment`, I get an error saying that doctrine is not able to create a `Page` entity. I guess this is happening because it's not finding the `Page` (but it should) so it's trying to create a new `Page` entity to later link it to the `Comment` entity that I'm trying to create.

Here is the method from my controller to create a `Comment`:

```
public function createAction()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $page = $this->getPage();

        $comment = new EntityComment();
        $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType(), $comment);

        if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() === 'POST') {
            $form->bind($this->getRequest());
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $comment->setPage($page);
                $comment->setUser($user);

                $em->persist($comment);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_comment_listing'));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('AcmeCommentBundle:Default:create.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I've checked my `Page` object in this controller (returned by `$this->getPage()` - which return the object stored in session) and it's a valid `Page` entity that exists (I've checked in the DB too).

I don't know what to do now and I can't find anyone having the same problem :(

This is the exact error message I have:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Acme\CommentBundle\Entity\Comment#page' that was not configured to
>   cascade persist operations for entity:
>   Acme\PageBundle\Entity\Page@000000005d8a1f2000000000753399d4. To solve
>   this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this
>   unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the
>   mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot
>   find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   'Acme\PageBundle\Entity\Page#__toString()' to get a clue.

But I don't want to add `cascade={"persist"}` because I don't want to create the page on cascade, but just link the existing one.

**UPDATE1:**

If I fetch the page before to set it, it's working. But I still don't know why I should.

```
public function createAction()
        {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            $page = $this->getPage();

            // Fetch the page from the repository
            $page = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmePageBundle:page')->findOneBy(array(
               'id' => $page->getId()
            ));

            $comment = new EntityComment();

            // Set the relation ManyToOne
            $comment->setPage($page);
            $comment->setUser($user);

            $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType(), $comment);

            if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() === 'POST') {
                $form->bind($this->getRequest());
                if ($form->isValid()) {
                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                    $em->persist($comment);
                    $em->flush();

                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_comment_listing'));
                }
            }

            return $this->render('AcmeCommentBundle:Default:create.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ));
        }
```

**UPDATE2:**

I've ended up storing the page_id in the session (instead of the full object) which I think is a better idea considering the fact that I won't have a use session to store but just the id. I'm also expecting Doctrine to cache the query when retrieving the `Page` Entity.

But can someone explain why I could not use the `Page` entity from the session? This is how I was setting the session:

```
$pages = $site->getPages(); // return doctrine collection
if (!$pages->isEmpty()) {         
    // Set the first page of the collection in session
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $session->set('page', $pages->first());
}
```

Comment: Are you not missing a `page_id` attribute in your `Comment` entity?

Comment: I should not have to define a `page_id` attribute in the `Comment` entity because there is already the relationship `ManyToOne` defined (which is suppose to handle this). In my database schema I have the correct fields in the `Comment` table: `user_id` and `page_id`

Comment: But then you need to add `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id")` under your `@ORM\ManyToOne`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok it's optional I was wrong!

Comment: yeah it's defaulting to this already ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your `Page` object is not known by the entity manager, the object come from the session. (The correct term is "detached" from the entity manager.)
That's why it tries to create a new one.

When you get an object from different source, you have to use `merge` function. (from the session, from an unserialize function, etc...)

Instead of

```
// Fetch the page from the repository
            $page = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmePageBundle:page')->findOneBy(array(
               'id' => $page->getId()
            ));
```

You can simply use :

```
$page = $em->merge($page);
```

It will help you if you want to work with object in your session.

More information on merging entities [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look tomorrow. But I'm not sure I want to store the full `Page` entity in the session. Never mind, I guess I can use the annotation too? I've seen `cascade={"merge"}`, is that the same?

Comment: So your solution is working, the annotation is not! That's not really handy :(